# simulate multiple connexions to the ethereum blockchain on a unique PC

Tags: transactions, connections

How to simulate that i have several connections to the ethereum blockchain(line in red in the picture)? what tools can i use to do this?Geth?

the goal is:

1. Sent requests or simultaneous transactions in order to get the data,
2. Then launch the same processing on the same data
3. and at the end compare the results obtained

how to simulate multiples connection on my computer[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of geth in the same PC, you have to configure different network ports so you don't have collisions, use separate directories and disable IPC or use different files for every instance.

```
geth --port 30303 --rpcport 8545 --wsport 8546 --ipcdisable --datadir "directory_previously_created" "other parameters"
```

To connect nodes between them use admin.addPeer from geth's console. To obtain its enode use admin.nodeInfo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out Ganache to run a local Ethereum instance (exposed on 127.0.0.1:8545): https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache

If you are more of a CLI type of person: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli

I'd then suggest using a library such as Ethers.js or Web3.js to interface with the Ethereum instance: https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#contract-execution
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/